# Issue while using typedef in c program

Tags: c, pointers, types, typedef

I have a function as given below:

```
void deleteNode ( node **my_head, int t_data )
{
 typedef (*my_head) head;    
}
```

I want to have an alias for the value of the double pointer (*my_head).
While compiling I get the following error:

```
<error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'head'>
```

I do have a workaround but I still need to make this work.
Can anyone please help me out with this!!

Comment: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'head'

Comment: You want a new variable? `node * head = *my_head`?

Comment: Without using a new variable I want to make an alias for (*my_head).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly notice the nomenclature `typedef`. It is used in *type* definition. To be precise, `typedef` is used to define a *new* type, not a variable name alias, as you expect.

As per the `c99` standard, chapter 6.7.2 type specifiers are

- void
- char
- short
- int
- long
- float
- double
- signed
- unsigned
- _Bool
- _Complex
- _Imaginary
- struct-or-union-specifier
- enum-specifier
- typedef-name

So, you can use `typdef` for these types. What you're trying is to use `typedef` with a ***variable name***. That's ***not*** allowed.

As others have specified, you have to use typedef in a format

```
typedef <old type name> <new alias>;
```

Comment: But I still need way out if I want to use head as (*my_head) and not as a type alias?

Comment: @AnshulTripathi I'm not sure if i have understood your requirement. Can you give a brief example?

Comment: I want to use (*my_head) thorugh out my function many times. Therefore, to reduce the effort of typing (*my_head) everytime I want an alias which replaces (*my_head) everytime when I use it in the function.

Comment: @AnshulTripathi well, if it's only about _reducing_ the type effort,  and without a new variable, you can try using `#define`, with a bit of caution with `()`, `{}` and `;`.

Comment: We can't write macro in local scope of a function. I have to again get a overhead of defining this alias macro at the beginning of the file. Is there no way out of making an alias in the function block itself?

Comment: @AnshulTripathi  ___overhead___ `of defining this alias macro at the beginning of the file` is it really? I don't think so. You've to do it once and only once. That's all.

Comment: I already tried writing a macro as follows:
`#define head (*my_head)`
This gives an error related to multiple definitions of the subsequent function written next to this function.

Comment: @AnshulTripathi i din't get you. can you show some example?

Comment: Thanks, it is working with Macro.
There was some compiler issue with the sequence of functions. If I use the same code with Macro and place the function below all the function definitions it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

You need to alias the type, not the variable name.

```
typedef node** head;
```

Comment: This does not solve the purpose for this case as I want to use head as (*my_head) and not as a type alias.

Comment: @AnshulTripathi Same problem as others, I too didn't get your question

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I want to use (*my_head) thorugh out my function many times. Therefore, to reduce the effort of typing (*my_head) everytime I want an alias which replaces (*my_head) everytime when I use it in the function.

Comment: I tried this approach but it doesn't work. The pointer (*my_head) remained unchanged when this function returns i.e. using local variable does not change the pointer (*my_head) when the function returns.

Answer (score 2):

syntax for typedef is

```
typedef <old type name> <new alias>;
```

so here you should use

```
typedef node** head
```

Comment: Is there any way out if I want to use head as (*my_head) and not as a type alias?

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I want to use (*my_head) thorugh out my function many times. Therefore, to reduce the effort of typing (*my_head) everytime I want an alias which replaces (*my_head) everytime when I use it in the function.